# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'sum_hours' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Its been nearly 2 months since i started to learn rails for doing some modifications on a plugin of Redmine in an enterprise (as a student learning the way of "life"), but this problem is something i cant find the solution anywhere.

Let me explain:

I needed to group a huge ammount of time entries by user_id and project_id(no problems with that) but if i do this i need to Sum the hours in those groups.

The estructure is something like this:

> | ID | project_id | user_id | issue_id | hours |

And this information is built up with this method :

```
def time_entries_for_user(user, options={})
    extra_conditions = options.delete(:conditions)
    return TimeEntry.select('*,sum(hours) as sum_hours').
      includes(self.includes).
      where(self.conditions([user], extra_conditions)).
      group('issue_id, time_entries.project_id').
      order('issues.id ASC')
end
```

I added the select because i needed all the column plus the sum one and the group by alone works well , but i cant make the Sum columns appear.
This is the json code from the result of this method:

```
{"test1 / SubProyectoTest1":{"logs":[{"id":24,"project_id":4,"user_id":1,"issue_id":10,"hours":6.0,"comments":"","activity_id":8,"spent_on":"2016-05-03","tyear":2016,"tmonth":5,"tweek":18,"created_on":"2016-05-03T11:07:09.000Z","updated_on":"2016-05-03T11:07:09.000Z","sum_hours":9.0}],"users":[{"id":1,.....
```

The funny thing is that in other method which groups by project , the Sum column appear.
This one works well :

```
def time_entries_for_all_users(project)
    return project.time_entries.select('*,sum(hours) as sum_hours').
    includes(self.includes).
    where(self.conditions(self.users)).
    group('issue_id,user_id')
      order('issues.id ASC')
    end


{"test1 / SubProyectoTest1":{"logs":[{"id":24,"project_id":4,"user_id":1,"issue_id":10,"hours":6.0,"comments":"","activity_id":8,"spent_on":"2016-05-03","tyear":2016,"tmonth":5,"tweek":18,"created_on":"2016-05-03T11:07:09.000Z","updated_on":"2016-05-03T11:07:09.000Z","sum_hours":9.0}],"users":[{"id":1.......
```

In the logs, this error shows :

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `sum_hours' for #)

Referring to this code on the view that renders the time entries:

```
 <% when l(:field_hours) %>
<strong><%= number_with_precision(time_entry.sum_hours, :precision => @precision) %></strong>
```

Well, you cant call something that doesn't exists...

2º time asking for help in StackOverflow so if you need more info because i forgot to write it , do it :) .

Regards and thanks.

EDITED:

Thanks to BoraMa and Emiliano, i get it to work adding the relation manually.
The code of the first sample changed to :

```
    def time_entries_for_user(user, options={})
        extra_conditions = options.delete(:conditions)

        return TimeEntry.select('*,sum(hours) as sum_hours').
              includes(self.includes).
              where(self.conditions([user], extra_conditions)).
              where("time_entries.user_id",user)
              group('issue_id, time_entries.project_id').
              order('issues.id ASC')
          end
   end
```

Though it only show one record with the proper sum of hours but,im trying to group by issue_id and it groups by user_id causing to show only 1 record.

EDITED 2:
FINALLY!! I didnt realize that the order of the methods can alter the result :/. The final code :

```
  def time_entries_for_user(user, options={})
    extra_conditions = options.delete(:conditions)

    return TimeEntry.group('time_entries.project_id,time_entries.issue_id').
      select('*,sum(hours) as sum_hours').
      includes(self.includes).
      where(self.conditions([user], extra_conditions)).
      where("time_entries.user_id",user)
      order('issues.id ASC')
  end
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests, the manually selected column (`sum_hours` in your case), is normally accessible as a "virtual" attribute when you execute the query on a model, as per your first example - the `time_entries_for_user` method.

However, it does not seem to work if you try to add a custom select to an *association of a record*. Then I get the exact same error as you (a `NoMethodError`). For this to start working, I'd advise to rewrite your second query (the `time_entries_for_all_users`) to a **form without using associations**, i.e. to something like this:

```
def time_entries_for_all_users(project)
  TimeEntry.select('*,sum(hours) as sum_hours').     # <- no association used here
      includes(self.includes).
      where(self.conditions(self.users)).
      where("time_entries.project_id", project.id).  # <- the assoc. is added here instead
      group('issue_id,user_id')
      order('issues.id ASC')
end
```

Nothe that instead of calling the `time_entries` association on the current `project` record, we are selecting all time entries having this project ID. This should return the same records as your original query but the custom columns should also work correctly. You'll probably need to update the query further so that your other conditions and includes work ok too.

As a second option, you can always define the association together with the manual select:

```
has_many :time_entries_with_hours_sum,  
         -> { select("time_entries.*, sum(hours) as sum_hours") }, class_name: "TimeEntry"
```

Then your custom column should be normally accessible using this new association:

```
project.time_entries_with_hours_sum.first.sum_hours
# => 9.0
```

Comment: The second sample its the one working, not the first though. I managed to change the code as you said and its working, at least i can see the field if i change the object to json but only with 1 record.
I really dont know why it wont use the group i added.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add a SUM column that way and convert to json you will have not problem, however if you try to access the field as an attribute, Rails won't be able to find it as it is not part of the model.

Either you convert to json the object to json in the view, or create a different method just for this case and retrieve only the sum (maybe using the specific *sum* method of ActiveRecord - for readibility's sake).

Comment: Yeah i thought something like that. The json part is only for readability here. 
I didnt use the sum method of ActiveRecord because it returns only the value of that column when i need the entire object plus another column.